# Delete a file name with spaces in between

Tags: java, file

i read on several posts that we for deleting a file through java which has spaces in the name, i can use delete() method (Java 6). eg:

```
 File f = new File("/mnt/test ex.txt");  
 f.delete();
```

but when I'm making a file object like this () :

```
 StringBuilder fullFileName = "C:/Temp_Folder\week month.xlsx";
 fileToRead = new File(fullFileName.toString());
 fileToRead.delete();
```

I'm not able to do so and i get the following exception :

java.io.FileNotFoundException: "C:\Temp_Folder\week month.xlsx" (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
What am i missing here?

P.s. : I tried using quotes on the filename as well without success

```
  fileToRead = new File('"'+fullFileName.toString()+'"');
```

Edit : I've edited the quotes on the stringBuilder (a type from my end). Actually the StringBuilder object is a parameter and we are appending objects to fetch the actual name. I just gave you the final declaration.
As far as week month.xlsx goes, that is the name of the file and not two different variables (which means the filename DOES have spaces in between; it could be something like

Name with spaces.xlsx

Thanks for the quick turnaround everyone.

Comment: You need quotes around that bit of code after fullFileName. Its a string builder.

Comment: Just use a String, not a StringBuilder.  Put double quote marks around your String literal, and escape the backslash by doubling it up.

Comment: You don't get that exception from this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do NOT need a specific treatment for file names with spaces in Java -- or any other programming language with a file access API for that matter.

Do not mix Java with a command interpreter.

In your case, your `File` should be declared as:

```
new File("C:\\Temp_Folder\\name with spaces.xlsx")
```

and that's it.

If Java reports a `FileNotFoundException` then there is a problem. Unfortunately, the `File` API is broken and this exception can be thrown if the file exists but you cannot read it, for instance. Have a look at the complete stack trace.

Do yourself a favour: use Java 7 and the new `Files` API. With this API, exceptions actually make some sense -- and a delete operation will not "silently" fail either.

As to building the filename itself, you can for example use `String.format()`:

```
final String filename = String.format("C:\\Temp_Folder\\%s %s.xlsx", month, week);
```

Comment: I think he wants to make the name dynamic. Just FYI. The `week` and `month` are one of his main concerns I think.

Comment: You are correct in saying that we do NOT need any specific treatment for file names with spaces in Java, but after much reiterations, i realized i had created an InputStream object using my intended file  which i did not close. After that it was a breeze.

Answer (score 1):

According to the exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: "C:\Temp_Folder\week month.xlsx"
```

You are looking for the following file:

```
"C:\Temp_Folder\week month.xlsx"
```

Note the quotes!  This file does not exist.

You will have to modify your code to ensure that your file name does not include the surrounding quotes (not needed).

I.e. (Assuming java 6 here)

```
File file = new File("C:\\Temp_Folder\\week month.xlsx");
file.delete();
```

Note, the backslash is an escape character hence it is doubled in the string.